# pset 6 DNA, checking database for matching profiles

Tags: python, cs50

I am currently on pset 6 dna in cs50, I have completed the majoraty of the problem, but I can't seem to wrap my head round the final step, checking the database for matching profiles.

all of my code is located below to provide context for variables, I am unsure on the usage of my if loop and what I should be comparing, I think I may be overcompilcating it so any help with understanding or solving this problem would be appriciated

```
# TODO: Read database file into a variable

database = []
filename = sys.argv[1]
with open(filename) as f:
    reader = csv.DictReader(f)
    for row in reader:
        database.append(row)

# TODO: Read DNA sequence file into a variable

sequence = []
filename = sys.argv[2]
with open(filename) as f:
    r = f.read()
for column in r:
    sequence.append(column)


# TODO: Find longest match of each STR in DNA sequence

subsequences = list(database[0].keys())[1:]
longest_sequence = {}
for subsequence in subsequences:
    longest_sequence[subsequence] = longest_match(sequence, subsequence)


# TODO: Check database for matching profiles
databaselen = len(database)
sequencelen = len(sequence)
str_counts = [longest_sequence[subsequence]]
for i in range(databaselen):
    for j in range(sequencelen):
        if str_counts[j] == database[i][1:][j]:
            print(database["name"])


return
```

Comment: Here are [some](https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=%5Bpython%5Dpset+6+dna+in+cs50) posts for that problem. With different search terms there are more results for pset6.

Comment: @ChrisCharley do you think my search terms are preventing my question from being answered?

Comment: I think your search for `longest_sequence` isn't doing what you think. And I don't see where `longest_match` is defined. You need to find the longest repeating STR's in the sequence file, not the STR's in `subsequences`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Before checking the database for matching profiles, you need to check your previous steps. When you do, you will find several problems:

1. First, `sequence` is not what you think it is. (You probably think
   it is a string.  Instead, it is a list of single character
   strings.) This occurs because you create `sequence` as a string, and
   are appending items to it.
2. Because of that error, `longest_match()` doesn't return the correct
   counts for the subsequences. As a result, you have no chance to find
   matches in the database.

The lesson: sometimes errors appear downstream from the real error. You need to check every line as you code.

Fix those errors, then work on the database match procedure. When you do, you will find additional errors.

1. You create variable `str_counts` which is the max count of any subsequence. That is not what you should be checking. You need to check the count for EVERY subsequence for each person against the database. (So, for sequence 1: `{'AGATC': 4, 'AATG': 1, 'TATC': 5}`).
2. Next, you are accessing elements of `database` incorrectly. `database` is a list of dictionaries (that uses keys). So, use list syntax to get each dictionary and dictionary syntax to get the key/value pairs.
3. Finally, you need to loop over each person and check their subsequence counts against the database. (Also, notice that STR values in `database` and  `longest_sequence` are different types.) Procedure should look something like this. You need to add the details.

Code:

```
# database is a LIST of people DICTIONARIES
for person in database: # to loop on people in the list
    # longest_sequence is a dictionary of STR:count values
    for STR in longest_sequence:  
    # Check ALL longest_sequence[STR] values against all person[STR] values
        # If ALL match, person is a match
        # Otherwise, person is NOT a match
```

Good luck.

Comment: hey thanks for the reply It's definately gave me more understanding and I've solved the first 2 problems, but I'm struggling on checking the count for every subsequence for each person against the database, to solve this do I need to change my for loop conditions?

Comment: Yes, you definitely need to modify your loop conditions. I updated my answer to include a outline of the procedure. I will let you figure out the details. :-)

Comment: `    for person in database:
        match = 0
    for STR in longest_sequence:
        if int(person[STR]) == longest_sequence[STR]:
         match += 1
        if match == len(subsequence):
            print("match")
        else:
            print(len(STR)) `
this is what my loops look like now, any tips or guidance as where i have gone wrong in the loops?

Comment: I'm struggling with checking all longest[sequence] str values against all person[str] values, I can't seem to get them to match

Comment: The code logic in your previous comment is pretty darn close (assuming you indented statements correctly). Note: once you find a match, you should print the matching name (not "match"). Or when you don't find a match, print "No match".

Comment: I think I'm really close... longest_sequence[subsequence] is not matching int(person[subsequence] ) and I'm unsure why, could this be a problem further up in the code? Thank you for the response, it really has helped me get closer!

Comment: At this point, you need to examine variable values to find which one is incorrect. You can either start at the beginning and go down, or work backwards from the error. Check `subsequence` for the correct STR subsequences from the CSV header. Then check the dictionary returned from `longest_match()`. Also check the `people` dictionaries in `database`. Something will look "off". Keep digging. :-)

Comment: I've discovered that it is the dictionary from longest match that is the problem, but I have no idea how to fix it